# Populating Android Spinner List with City Names

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I am developing an android application and got stuck at this issue - all I want to do is populate my spinner drop down menu in android with the list of cities in USA. But I am not able to find a proper way to do the same.

I know that we can make a `<string-array>` and put items in there to populate the spinner. But considering the number of cities there are, I don't think its the best idea. Can anyone please tell a better way to do it?

Is there any XML File for the same?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you planning on getting the list of city names? I have a spinner I'm working on currently with a smaller list, but it's coming through a web service into an ArrayList, which is then used to populate the spinner. No need to have a string-array with all possible items.

Comment: @BenjaminS - I am actually making a form in which a user can select a city from the spinner and then go on and use that city to search certain items. Is there any readily available web service for the same?

Comment: Our web service is in-house, so unless you or someone you were working with was planning on writing one, not that I know of. I'm a newbie myself, but I would think at this point you'd either need to create a large string-array, or perhaps use some kind of external resource file?

Comment: Take the values from a database. Here's a possible source to fill it up:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_the_United_States